# Passing public member function pointer to a constructor

Tags: c++

I want to allow for passing a concrete public member function implementation at construction time.
It would be ideal if I could call that public member function using its name.

This example can illustrate it the best:

```
class A {
    typedef int (A::*mem)(void) const;

public:
    A(int aa) : a(aa) {};
    A(int aa, mem mm) : m(mm), a(aa) {}; // How to use this?

    mem m;

private:
    int a;
};

int main() {
    A a(3);
    // (a.*m)(); // ‘m’ was not declared in this scope
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose `A` has a member function named `foo` (matching the signature of `typedef` `mem`), then you can

```
A a(3, &A::foo); // pass member function pointer pointing to A::foo
(a.*(a.m))();    // call from the member function pointer on object a
```

[LIVE](https://rextester.com/MEJU36444)

**EDIT**

If you want the caller to provide the implementation liek lambda, you can use `std::function` instead.

```
class A {
    typedef std::function<int()> mem;

public:
    A(int aa) : a(aa) {};
    A(int aa, mem mm) : m(mm), a(aa) {}; // How to use this?

    mem m;

private:
    int a;
};
```

then

```
A a(3, [] { std::cout << "hello"; return 0; });
(a.m)();
```

[LIVE](https://rextester.com/GFGS75229)

Comment: Doesn't this mean that `A::foo` is declared in `A`? I need `foo` to be something that someone who uses `A`s public API can provide on their own. For example, something similar to lambda expression. This rather looks like an indirection.

Comment: @foki Then you don't want a pointer-to-member.  It sounds like you want something like `std::function`.

Comment: @songyuanyao Yes, that would work. Could you please make it an answer?

Comment: @foki Fine, added.